# Including an external javascript script breaks the submission of a form which has remote:true

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I have a new.html.erb file which contains a form to create a new listing.
Now this page also has a dropzone element taken from dropzone.js for letting the users drop there images which later gets uploaded.

This form has remote:true

Here are the codes:-

/*new.html.erb*/

```
<div class="ui padded page grid">

  <div class="ui eight wide column">

    <%=form_for @listing, :html=> { class:'ui form centered black segment'},remote: true do |f|%>

    <div class="ui black ribbon label">
        <i class="signup icon"></i> New Listing
      </div>
      <h2 class="ui header">
        <i class="settings icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
          Create New Listing
          <div class="sub header">Manage your preferences</div>
        </div>
      </h2>

      <div class="required field">
        <label>Title</label>  
        <%=f.text_field :title,placeholder:'Title of the listing'%>
      </div>
      <div class="two fields">

        <div class="required field">
          <label>Pet</label>
          <%= f.select(:pet_type,options_for_select([['Dog',1,{class:'item'}],['Cat',2,{class:'item'}],['Bird',3,{class:'item'}]]),{prompt:'Pet'},class:'ui dropdown pet_type')%>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>Breed</label>
          <%= f.select(:breed_type,options_for_select(Breed.all.collect{|x| [x.name,x.id,class:'item']}),{prompt:'Breed'},class:'ui dropdown disabled breed_type')%>
        </div>



      </div>
      <div class="two fields">
        <div class="required field">
          <label>Gender</label>
          <%= f.select(:gender,options_for_select([['Male',1,{class:'item'}],['Female',2,{class:'item'}]]),{prompt:'Gender'},class:'ui dropdown gender')%>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>State</label>
          <select class="ui search dropdown">
            <option value="">State</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="required field">
        <label>Tell everyone in short about your pet</label>
        <%=f.text_area :love_for_pets%>
      </div>
      <h4 class="ui dividing header">Additional Info</h4>
      <div class="two fields">
        <div class="required field">
          <label>Price</label>
          <div class="ui icon input">
            <%=f.text_field :price,placeholder:"Price"%>
            <i class="rupee icon"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>Phone Number</label>
          <div class="ui icon input">
            <%=f.text_field :phone_no,placeholder:"Phone_no"%>
            <i class="call icon"></i>
          </div>
        </div>



</div>



<div class="ui hidden divider"></div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hot-deals">
    <label>I agree to the <a href="#">Terms of Service</a>.</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui error message">
  <div class="header">We noticed some issues</div>
</div>
<%=f.submit 'Register',class:'ui button'%>
<div class="ui error message"></div>
<%end%>


</div>

<div class="ui eight wide column">

  <div class="ui black segment dropzone" id="media-dropzone">
    <div class="ui blue right ribbon label">
        <i class="upload icon"></i> Upload Images
      </div>

  <h2 class="ui center aligned icon header dz-message">
    <i class="upload icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      Upload File
      <div class="sub header">Drop your images here</div>
    </div>
  </h2>
</div>
</div>


</div>
```

/*ListingController*/

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @breeds=Breed.all
        @listing=Listing.new
    end

    def create
        @listing=Listing.new(listing_params)
        if @listing.save
            session[:listing]=@listing.id
            respond_to do |format|
                format.js
            end
        end
    end
    def media
        @listing=Listing.find(session[:listing])
        puts params
        @photo=Photo.new(file_name:params[:file],listing:@listing)
        if @photo.save!
            respond_to do |format|
                format.json{render :json=>@photo}

            end
        end

    end


    private
    def listing_params
        params.require(:listing).permit!
    end

end
```

/*listing.js*/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   

    Dropzone.options.mediaDropzone=false;


    mediaDropzone=new Dropzone('div#media-dropzone',
    {
      url:"/listings/media",
      headers: 
      {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      autoProcessQueue:false,
      addRemoveLinks:true,
      parallelUploads: 10
    });
    mediaDropzone.on("success",function(file,responseText)
    {
      console.log(responseText.file_name.url);
      console.log(responseText);
    });


});
```

/*create.js.erb*/

```
mediaDropzone.processQueue();
```

/*routes.rb*/

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  root 'prime_petz#home'

  get 'prime_petz/home'

  get 'prime_petz/about'

  get 'prime_petz/contact'

  post 'listings/media'

  resources :listings
  resources :prime_petz
end
```

Now everything works fine here, till the time I create a script like this

/*dynamic_breeds.js.erb*/

```
  var breeds= new Array();
    <% for breed in Breed.all %>
      breeds.push(new Array(<%= breed.pet_id %>, '<%=breed.name %>', <%= breed.id %>));
    <% end%>

    function petSelected() {
      pet_id = $('#listing_pet_type').val();
      options = document.getElementById('listing_breed_type').options;
      options.length = 1;
      for(var i=0;i<breeds.length;i++)
      {
        if (breeds[i][0] == pet_id) {
          options[options.length] = new Option(breeds[i][1], breeds[i][2]);
        }
      };
      if (options.length == 1) {
        $('.breed_type').addClass('disabled');
      } else {
        $('.breed_type').removeClass('disabled')
      }
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.pet_type').dropdown({
     onChange:petSelected
    });

});
```

What this script does is,it will populate the breed dropdown based on the pet dropdown)

This script works properly, but the new.html.erb form on submission gives me an error of UnknownFormat error at the line

```
respond_to do|format|
format.js
end
```

Can anyone please explain why I am getting this error only when I use this script.

/*application.js*/

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

// Loads all Semantic javascripts
//= require semantic-ui

//= require dropzone

//= require cloudinary
//= require dynamic_breeds


//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this might be a strange problem what we have here. I have tried the same with a sample and there seems to be a problem with the dropdown function you are calling in document.ready. I find it funny how a jquery function breaks the functionality here. Change it to the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.pet_type').change(function(){
    petSelected();
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be you're only handling if the requested format is .js, so if the form is asking for HTML it doesn't know what to do, try to add `format.html` as well.

Comment: This is a remote:true form,It is required to make an ajax call.I tried format.html{render 'new'},but then it takes me to the localhost:3000/listings instead of localhost:3000/listings/new.If I remove this script then the form functions like an ajax form